# How to mock axios.CancelToken using Jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to unit test the following module, but getting the below error. Can someone please share any ideas on how to mock `axios.CancelToken()` here? or How test this part?

service.js

```
let myCancelToken
export async function myTestFuncService (name) {
  if (myCancelToken) {
    myCancelToken.cancel()
  }
  myCancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source()
  try {
    return axios.get(`mypath/${name}`, {
      cancelToken: myCancelToken.token
    })
  } catch (e) {
    return e
  }
}
```

service.test.js

```
import * as myModule from './service.js'
import axios from 'axios'
jest.mock('axios')

it('test myTestFuncService', async () => {
    const testData = {
      data: {
        response: 'some test data'
      }
    }
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(testData))
    await expect(
      myModule.myTestFuncService('ABC')
    ).resolves.toBe(testData)
  })
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'cancel' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jest.spyOn()` to mock `axios.CancelToken.source()` and `axios.get()` methods.

In addition, since you have defined the variable `myCancelToken` in the scope of the module, after the module is requested and the `myTestFuncService` method is executed, `myCancelToken` will be assigned a value, and the next time the module is requested, it will be fetched from the `request.cache` and affect the later test cases later. Therefore, you need to use `jest.resetModules()` to clear the module's cache to ensure that different test cases use the "fresh" module.

E.g.

`service.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

let myCancelToken;
export async function myTestFuncService(name) {
  if (myCancelToken) {
    myCancelToken.cancel();
  }
  myCancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();
  try {
    return await axios.get(`mypath/${name}`, {
      cancelToken: myCancelToken.token,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

`service.test.js`:

```js
describe('68673646', () => {
  let mod;
  let axios;
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    mod = require('./service');
    axios = require('axios').default;
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should get name', async () => {
    const cancelTokenSource = { cancel: jest.fn(), token: { reason: { message: 'user canceled' } } };
    jest.spyOn(axios.CancelToken, 'source').mockReturnValueOnce(cancelTokenSource);
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce('teresa teng');
    await mod.myTestFuncService('ABC');
    expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith('mypath/ABC', { cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token });
    expect(axios.CancelToken.source).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('should cancel if cancel token exists', async () => {
    const cancelTokenSource = { cancel: jest.fn(), token: { reason: { message: 'user canceled' } } };
    jest.spyOn(axios.CancelToken, 'source').mockReturnValue(cancelTokenSource);
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValue('teresa teng');
    await mod.myTestFuncService('ABC');
    expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith('mypath/ABC', { cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token });
    expect(axios.CancelToken.source).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    await mod.myTestFuncService('DEF');
    expect(cancelTokenSource.cancel).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith('mypath/DEF', { cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68673646/service.test.js (7.34 s)
  68673646
    ✓ should get name (6360 ms)
    ✓ should cancel if cancel token exists (7 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |    87.5 |      100 |     100 |    87.5 |                   
 service.js |    87.5 |      100 |     100 |    87.5 | 14                
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.82 s, estimated 8 s
```

Answer (score 0):

I was testing if cancelToken works on unmount of the component like this:

```js
test('Should stop pending request in case the component is unmounted', async () => {
            const { result, unmount } = renderHook(() =>
                // hook goes here
            );
    
            expect(result.current.cancelTokenSource.token.reason).not.toBeDefined();
    
            unmount();
    
            expect(result.current.cancelTokenSource.token.reason).toBeDefined();
        });
```

After `cancelToken` is cancelled the reason field is added to the object, which let us test the cancellation like this.
We don't mock the token itself, but that also might be a way for some cases.